# How to get top items viewed and downloaded for all time after sharding SOLR statistics in DSpace?

Tags: solr, dspace

Previously, before I shard my SOLR statistics, I am able to display the top 10 most viewed and most downloaded items of all time using this code: [Add top 10 most downloaded items to /statistics-home](https://gist.github.com/eulereadgbe/52401d5ae1ce290398dd59ae4eaf75f1)

Our statistics only dates back to the year 2011, so after sharding, we have 10 statistics core from 2011 up to the present year which is 2020.

My question now is how to get the most viewed/downloaded items for all the combined years since I can no longer use the default SOLR statistics URL because using it will only get the current year. When I tail my `solr.log` upon viewing the `/statistics-home` URL, it is querying every statistics core.

How did the URL `/statistics-home` manage to get the top item views even after sharding the SOLR statistics? Any tips on querying multiple SOLR statistics core from XMLUI?

Answer (score 0):

After tailing my `solr.log`, I found out that I just need to add the parameter `shards` in my original SOLR query.

So previously when doing a query for the all-time downloaded items, I used this query:

```
/solr/statistics/select?q=type:0+-isBot:true+statistics_type:view&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=owningItem&fq=bundleName:ORIGINAL&facet.sort=count&facet.limit=10&rows=0&wt=json
```

Now, I just inserted the parameter `&shards=localhost:8080/solr/statistics-2011,localhost:8080/solr/statistics-2012,localhost:8080/solr/statistics-n…` with all my sharded statistics core. It turned out that I don't need to join queries.

Regarding on the querying Solr statistics from XMLUI, I just created a variable name for shards where I input all the sharded statistics core that I have. I don't know if there are other ways besides manually adding each sharded statistics core per year but right now this will suffice for my current needs.